# When the CPU is very busy, my multithreaded java program gets an unexpected Exception

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception, cpu-usage

I have been doing a multithreaded java program which will make CPU usage gradually reach 100%. When CPU usage is low, the program is running correctly; but when the CPU is near 100%, my program throws a `NullPointerException`.

I put objects in an `ArrayList`. When I get an object token from the ArrayList, there [sometimes] is a `null` object, so when I invoke a method on the object, it throws a NullPointerException.

But I have checked the program, and no `null` object is ever put in the `ArrayList`.

So, I guess this is because of 100% CPU usage. Can anyone explain me the reason?

Comment: Sounds like a logical bug introduced by mutlithreading. We would need your code in order to analyse your situation.

Comment: Better use a profiler for such things.. I don't think NPE will be caused by high CPU usage..

Comment: **unsynchronized operations will always lead to indeterminate outcomes**. It sounds like you are not synchronizing correctly on a `Collection` that is not thread safe. This is called a race hazard.

Comment: No. If a threadsafe method works when run once, it also works when run multiple times simultaneously. The likely reason for this is a race condition on some resource, which has a greater likelihood to happen as more treads are added. In addition, you probably shouldn't design a program that intentionally overloads the CPU, as it can lead to performance degradation as the OS get's stuck in context switch thrashing.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I agree with the sentiment, but it's a bit more complicated than 'unsynchronized operations' (as I'm sure you know) - `volatile` variables are an alternative to synchronization with slightly different semantics, and `final` fields often don't need to be synchronized either. (if references don't escape the constructor)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt of course. My point is that without synchronization there is no "happens before" relationship. The code will run in an indeterminate manner - but might, with the correct use of other language constructs, result in something useful.

Answer (score 4):

Writing multi-threaded code (multiple threads that access the same data structures) is difficult and requires knowledge and experience that goes beyond what you can provide in an SO answer.

The Java Memory Model defines how memory operates when multiple threads access the same data.

That said, from your description I can tell you one thing that you can change. Do not use an `ArrayList` directly with multiple threads. An ArrayList does not protect itself against so-called data races.

Instead, use `Collections.synchronizedList(...)` to create a list that protects its internal data structures against data races:

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
```

This will ensure that you will no longer get a `null` object out of your list when you haven't put a `null` object in it.

However this doesn't resolve more complicated data races when multiple threads operate on the objects that you retrieve from the list.

Comment: `synchronizedXXX` also doesn't protect compound operations. It's very hard to make any meaningful recommendations without seeing the OPs code.

Comment: I know, but this certainly solves the problem of the OP: they get `null` out of the list when they didn't put any `null` in it. That's a typical data race caused by memory inconsistency within the internal data structures of the list. And that's the problem that the OP has described in their question.

Comment: I have solved my problem, based on your answer. Thank you! @Erwin Bolwidt